# File URL appears when hosting serial terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, serial

I'm using my Apple IIGS as a serial terminal (using Modem.MGR as a vt220 emulator) to OS X 10.9.2.

I open the session by typing `screen /dev/tty.usbserial 19200` on the Mac, and then `Ctrl+A Shift+Colon` and `exec ::: /usr/libexec/getty vt220`, and a login prompt appears on the terminal. This all works great. However, I get output like this:

```
Last login: Wed Mar  5 15:49:21 on ttys002
7;file://defiant.local/Users/lafrance[15:50:50] [lafrance@defiant ~]$
```

From the timestamp on is my actual prompt (from `export PS1`), and `defiant.local` is my machine's hostname. I'm just not sure why `getty` is sending the current path. This doesn't happen when I open Terminal.app.

Comment: Is this line repeated for every prompt, or only the postlogin?

Comment: Every prompt.

I've discovered that running getty outside of screen (using launchctl) doesn't cause this behavior, which is interesting.

Comment: I have a feeling that it may be part of some control code that is being sent... You may want to use another tool to look at the raw data on that port, and see what comes before/after that.

Comment: Also, take a look at then environment variable TERM, which may be set wrong, also,try starting getty directly, without any interaction from screen "getty 19200 tty.usbserial vt220", you will need to sudo that one.